# Increase variable CSS

Tags: css, variables

Like in the topic, is there any way to increase variable in the CSS? I want to increse per-cents but I don't know how to, to be honest.

```
--variable: ???
```

> --variable: x + 1%?

Comment: Can you give an example of where and how you use this variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in css unfortunately. You can use SASS to accompolish this, however. It's a pre-processor for css: http://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you may be looking for is the **calc** function:

```
#id {
    width: calc(50% + 50px);
}
```

In this example, the `id` div will have take up 50 pixels **more** than 50% of the width of the parent.